# How to insert files, document

Tags: discussion

I want insert source files to be uploaded. In your code block to post my code means it show error at "your code length should be long".

Can any one provide a suggestion?

Comment: This question would belong on Meta. It needs a lot of improvement first, though.

Comment: Currently there isn't. Maybe you can use external code editors like plunker and post the link in your question?

Comment: @ManojKumar: No. As Magisch answered: _"If your code is too long and unwieldy to post into a question, you should probably work on composing a Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example first."_

Answer (score 5):

There's no way for you to upload a file currently.

If your code is too long and unwieldy to post into a question, you should probably work on composing a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) first.

We don't need to see all your code, only the relevant parts.

Comment: And what is the suggested way to upload a file that is used as test data, for example?